# Where are stored PendingIntents? Big trap of using

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

In my project i have tried out some possibilities and limitations of `PendingIntent`

So i have created some notification, that opens an activity by tapping

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
intent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_ITEM_NAME, "ItemName");
intent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_ITEM_ID, itemId);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
// properties set
;

notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(10), notificationBuilder.build());
```

at begin was everithing good, until i have placed other item to show in `NotificationActivity` by tap on notification.

Here starts problems: in `NotificationActivity` was still showed previous item.

After some search it could be solved with:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

BUT: if i have in same time many notifications, then i always see only last item, `PendingIntent` was created for.

Second parameter of `getActivity` is `requestCode`. So when i update solution to

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, new Random().nextInt(1000), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Then also many items are supported, and if for some reason the random makes me same numbers, the content in `NotificationActivity` will be the same.

So to 99% the solution is good, yes? **NO**

Again to first approach

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

If i set **new extras**  for intent -> **old extras** will be readed.

In other words: by `new Random().nextInt(1000)` somewhere in the system of android device will be stored till **1000** `PendingIntents` for one of activities i have **forever**

So here are the **questions**:

- *Where all this PendingIntents stored?*
- *How to clear it?*

With *How to clear it*, i mean a way to remove all currently maked `PendingIntents` with some `Random` as `requestCode`, so that in clear way with only one notification at time i could use

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

with different items

Comment: Do not use random but something meaningful ... FX if you wana show many different notifications then for each use different request code...

Comment: what do you mean with `FX` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PendingIntent`s are stored in non-persistent storage. When the device restarts, they are all gone.

Also, if you create a `PendingIntent` and put it in a `Notification`, once the `Notification` is gone (dismissed, opened, etc.) the `PendingIntent` is no longer in use and will be deleted.

Generally you should not use random numbers for the `requestCode` as this is no guarantee of uniqueness. You need to find a way to make your `PendingIntent` unique if you want to have many of them existing in parallel.

Comment: i have tested. By tests i have used same `requestCode` and **no** `Flags`.  First i have created a `PendingIntent` with item 1. have opened. notification was gone. then i have created second `PendingIntent` with item 2. it was showed item 1 => PendingIntent is not deleted

Comment: OK, not sure what you are getting at. If you only ever want to have 1 active `PendingIntent` then you need to use `PendingIntent.UPDATE_CURRENT`

Comment: You say, that `PendingIntent` would be removed, when dismissed. I say, no, it wouldn't. i thought i had explained it well in my question. I want to know the way, how to **really remove** stored `PendingIntents`. Restart of device i have not checked yet, but that could not be solution, if somebody newer makes restart of device.

Comment: You can't assume when they will be deleted. They are reference counted. This means when there are no more references to them, they will be deleted. Your app might have had a reference to the one that you put in the `Notification` which is why it was not deleted. You have no control over this, so you need to program as if you don't know. A `PendingIntent` is not large, so do not worry about how many you create.